# How to redirect to login page if user not authenticate in vue 3 and Laravel as backend

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

sanjayacloud
OP
Posted 1 hour ago
Ten Thousand Strong Achievement Badge
How to redirect to login page if user not authenticate in vue 3 and Laravel as backend
Hi,

I want to know how can i redirect user to login if user not authenticate in vue 3 with Laravel as backend. I am use vue 3 as front end separately. And I use Laravel as backend.

Here is my router/index.js file

```
import {createRouter, createWebHistory} from "vue-router";
import Dashboard from "../views/admin/Dashboard.vue";
import Home from "../views/Home.vue";
import Login from "../views/Login.vue";
import Register from "../views/Register.vue";
import Unauthorized from "../views/Unauthorized.vue";
import Users from "../views/admin/manage-user/Users.vue";
import Roles from "../views/admin/manage-user/Roles.vue";
import Permissions from "../views/admin/manage-user/Permissions.vue";


const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        name: "Home",
        component: Home,
        meta: {
            authRequired: 'false',
        },
    },
    {
        path: '/admin',
        children:[
            {path: 'dashboard', name: "Dashboard", component: Dashboard},
            {path: 'users', name: "Users", component: Users},
            {path: 'roles', name: "Roles", component: Roles},
            {path: 'permissions', name: "Permissions", component: Permissions},
        ],
        meta: {

        },
    },
    {
        path: '/login',
        name: "Login",
        component: Login,
        meta: {

        },
    },
    {
        path: '/register',
        name: "Register",
        component: Register,
        meta: {

        },
    },
    {
        path: '/unauthorized',
        name: 'Unauthorized',
        component: Unauthorized,
        meta: {

        },
    }
];

const router = createRouter( {
   history: createWebHistory(),
   routes,
});


export default router;
```

Here if my store/auth.js file

```
import {defineStore} from "pinia";
import axios from "axios";

export const useAuthStore = defineStore("auth", {
    state: () => ({
        authUser: null,
        authErrors: [],
        authStatus: null,
        userRoles: null,
        userPermissions: null,
    }),

    getters: {
        user: (state) => state.authUser,
        errors: (state) => state.authErrors,
        status: (state) => state.authStatus,
        user_roles: (state) => state.userRoles,
        user_permissions: (state) => state.userPermissions,
    },
    actions: {
        async getToken() {
            await axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie');
        },
        async getUser() {
            await  this.getToken();
            const data = await axios.get('/api/user');
            this.authUser = data.data;
            this.userRoles = data.data.roles;
            this.userPermissions = data.data.permissions;
        },

        async handleLogin (data)  {
            this.authErrors = [];
            await this.getToken();
            try {
                await axios.post('/api/login',{
                    email: data.email,
                    password: data.password,
                });
                this.router.push('/admin/dashboard');

            } catch (error) {
                if (error.response.status === 422){
                    this.authErrors = error.response.data.errors;
                }
            }
        },

        async handleRegister  (data) {
            this.authErrors = [];
            await this.getToken();
            try {
                await axios.post('/api/register', {
                    name: data.name,
                    email: data.email,
                    password: data.password,
                    password_confirmation: data.password_confirmation,
                });
                this.router.push("/");

            } catch (error) {
                if (error.response.status === 422){
                    this.authErrors = error.response.data.errors;
                }
            }
        },

        async handleLogout () {
            await axios.post('logout');
            this.authUser = null;
            this.router.push('/login');
        },

        async handleForgotPassword(email) {

            this.authErrors = [];
            await this.getToken();

            try {
                const response = await axios.post('forgot-password', {
                    email: email,
                });
                this.authStatus = response.data.status;
            } catch (error) {
                if (error.response.status === 422){
                    this.authErrors = error.response.data.errors;
                }
            }
        },

        async handleResetPassword(resetData) {
            this.authErrors = [];

            try {

                const response =  await axios.post('reset-password', resetData);
                this.authStatus = response.data.status;
            } catch (error) {
                if (error.response.status === 422){
                    this.authErrors = error.response.data.errors;
                }
            }
        },

    },
});
```

Here is my Dashbaord.vue component

```
<script setup>
 import {onMounted} from "vue";
 import {useAuthStore} from "../../stores/auth.js";
import DashboardLayout from "../../layouts/DashboardLayout.vue";
const authStore = useAuthStore();
onMounted(async () => {
    if (authStore.user){
        await authStore.getUser();
    }
 });
</script>
<template>
<DashboardLayout>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap align-items-center pt-3 pb-2 mb-3 border-bottom">
        <h1 class="h2">Dashboard</h1>
        <div class="btn-toolbar mb-2 mb-md-0">
            <div class="btn-group me-2">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Share</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Export</button>
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle">
                <span data-feather="calendar"></span>
                This week
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
  <h2>Section title {{authStore.user_permissions?.some((p) => p.name === 'edit_user')}}</h2>
  <div class="table-responsive">

  </div>
</DashboardLayout>
</template>
```

Please note i am use vue with pinia. And vue app is separate from laravel backend.

Answer (score 0):

Use Navigation Guards to check auth status before every redirection.

[Navigation Guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards)

```
// router/index.js
import { useAuthStore } from 'store/auth.js'

router.beforeEach(async (to, from) => {
  const autoStore = useAuthStore();

  if (
    // make sure the user is authenticated
    !autoStore.authUser &&
    // ❗️ Avoid an infinite redirect
    to.name !== 'Login'
  ) {
    // redirect the user to the login page
    return { name: 'Login' }
  }
})
```

Comment: Now I am getting this error when I am login: 

'Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'icons')'